# Intercept external service call and stub it

Tags: java, kotlin, interceptor, stub, intercept

I have an external team's package and I want to use one of the functions inside it.

```
//External package

class A (serviceExternalClient){
    methodB {
        value = serviceExternalClient.callExternalService()
        otherProcesses(value)
    }
}

class A2 (serviceExternalClient){
    methodB {
        value = serviceExternalClient.callExternalService2()
        otherProcesses(value)
    }
}

...

class AN (serviceExternalClient){
    methodB {
        value = serviceExternalClient.callExternalServiceN()
        otherProcesses(value)
    }
}
```

class A is public and I want to use methodB in all A classes but I don't have access to `serviceExternal` service so **I want to intercept or stub callExternalService** to return default values so that `otherProcesses` works and I can receive its results.

serviceExternalClient is injected using Dependency Injection.

I heard about using Reflection but couldn't figure out how to abstract it.

I ultimately want to do,

```
A.methodB()
```

but the external call is blocking the subsequent operation since I don't have access to it.  The data provided by external call is irrelavant to me.